# EDMX doesn't show the UI designer - gets directly into the XML file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I've reinstalled my laptop - Windows 7, VS2010, VS2010 SP1, SQL2008  and SQL2008 SP2.
I've also done windows updates - no updates available from update window anymore

The issue I've is: When I double click on the EDMX file it gets directly in to the XML. Why is that?
I don't get any error....

I can't do update from Database or add entities from Database etc....

I googled and found you should do open with and choose XML and then close XML and double click again. I've tried several options (open with ) and I don't get the UI Designer for my Entity Framework (edmx ) file.

I clicked on the properties of the file (*.edmx)
and I see Cusotmtool: EntityModelCodeGenerator and build action : EntityDeploy

I then right clicked on EDMX and choose 'Run Custom Tool" and then I receive this error
"cannot find custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' on this system."

I checked VS2010 and VS2010 SP1 is installed. I did again install from DVD and choose REPAIR and I still have this problem....

so what could be problem?

thanks

Comment: Does the exact same thing happen with a brand new EF model in a brand new project? If so, reinstall VS.

Comment: ok. I'll check it when I'm at home and let you know  in couple of hours.

Comment: @Craig: I just try to create a new EDMX file... but when I do add new item, I don't see any EF xxxx, mentioned in the window... so I assume something went wrong during install VS2010.. If I reinstall VS2010 (will do repair), do I need reinstall VS2010 SP1 and SQL2008 SP2 too?

Comment: EF designer didn't change in SP 1, I think. But you still want SP 1. Use Help -> About to see what you have.

Comment: @Craig: I re-installed (choose repair) took 3 hours and everything went ok 2x restarted and I still have the same issue: now I see when I right click on EDMX and choos run customtool I get this error "cannot find custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' on this system." so something is not installed but why?

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps "Repair" isn't repairing well?

Answer (score 1):

you had unchecked some of recommended features while installing the Visual Studio. Just Reinstall the visual studio to configure the features. after installation open the .edmx file with the "ADO.Net Entity Framwork designer".

Comment: if you have any query please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try **devenv.exe** option **/resetskippkgs**, then solve the error.

Comment: ok. I'll check it when I'm at home and let you know  in couple of hours.

Comment: this didn't help I think the problem is VS2010 is not installed well.. Because I don't see EF in the Add new item window. (just see that)

Comment: I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171027/edmx-no-longer-opens-in-designer-after-uninstalling-entity-framework-power-tools

Answer (score 0):

The question is about VS2010, but if you're looking at the same problem on a newer Visual Studio (e.g. VS2013), you probably need to reapply the latest VS update (worked for me) or reinstall VS.