# edmx no longer opens in designer after uninstalling Entity Framework Power tools

Tags: entity-framework

I am using vs 2013 update 4
I uninstalled Entity Framework Power tools and now when I open my edmx it only opens as xml
I have looked at projects that use Entity Framework 6.1 and 6.2 beta, and both have the problem.

In addition if I right click the edmx and select Run Custom Tool, I get an error 
Canot find custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' on this system.

I have since reinstalled Power Tools but the problem remains

I have run Visual Studio Repair

I have removed and then re-added Entity Framework

When I try to create a new edmx in a new project, and click New Item, I can not see an option to add
 ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: Try reinstalling the EF nuget packages.

Comment: Ah, I important to remove and then re-add the nuget package. Just upgrading doesn't work.  I now have a message saying failed to initialise Powershell host  Installed failed Rolling back.

Comment: Was able to install from PM>   ( after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353951/cant-install-nuget-package-because-of-failed-to-initialize-the-powershell-host )

Answer (score 3):

I re-installed  the Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2013 from 
[the download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

and this solved the problem